# How to delete files during the creation of an archive immediately after being added to the archive?

Tags: batch-file, winrar

I've tried using WinRAR's command line utility **rar.exe**, but it always first creates an archive and then deletes the original file after archive is already created.

Basically what I'm trying to do is adding multiple large files into one archive, but I'm running short on free space.

What's actually happening:

1. File1 added to archive x.rar
2. File2 added to archive x.rar
3. File3 added to archive x.rar
4. File1 deleted
5. File2 deleted
6. File3 deleted

What I hope to achieve:

1. File1 added to archive x.rar
2. File1 deleted
3. File2 added to archive x.rar
4. File2 deleted
5. File3 added to archive x.rar
6. File3 deleted

Is there any way to make this happen?

Comment: What happens if something crashes the process (like running out of free disk space) and the archive can't be created, but the files have already been deleted?

Comment: Yes, there is a way, but I'd definitely regard Ken White's advice! the standard way is the safest. Anyway, to safely (!?) do it your way, you could do in a loop: add file to temporary archive, copy temporary archive to final place (overwrite former one), delete file upon success; so if something happens you have the already processed files in the final archive; though this approach is going to be slooow; the only advantage might be the maximum amount of occupied disk space, depending on the achievable compression ratio, the number of files...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The batch file below could be used to move one file after the other in a specified source folder into a RAR archive.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "SourceFolder=C:\Temp"

for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "%SourceFolder%\*" /A-D /B 2^>nul') do "%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\Rar.exe" m -cfg- -ep -idcdp -m4 -y -- "%SourceFolder%\Archiv.rar" "%SourceFolder%\%%I" || goto CreationError
goto EndBatch

:CreationError
echo/
pause

:EndBatch
endlocal
```

But I doubt that this is really helpful for you on not enough storage space to create the archive file with the large files one after the other. `Rar.exe` has to create a temporary copy of the existing archive file on updating an existing archive file with adding one more file which most likely results again in an out of free storage space condition.

A deletion of a file immediately on being added is not possible without running two processes. The first process starts `Rar.exe` as separate process, but captures its output line by line and deletes a file added by `Rar.exe` to the archive while `Rar.exe` is running as separate process. But I think this is impossible to achieve with a batch file.

I suggest to *Run as administrator* Windows **Disk Cleanup** tool and use it to delete all files no longer needed. The *Windows Update Cleanup* offered by Windows **Disk Cleanup** tool on being run as administrator frees usually several gigabytes of storage space on this cleanup tool never run before. After manually executed necessary Windows restart, although not displayed that the Windows restart is necessary to finish *Windows Update Cleanup*, delete manually as administrator all folders and files in folder `%SystemRoot%\SoftwareDistribution\Download` (Windows security update packages already installed after Windows restart and sometimes not deleted automatically as it should be always done by Windows Update) and in folder `%SystemRoot%\Temp` (temporary files folder of system processes) to get even more free storage space back. Please wait on restart of Windows until Windows desktop is shown again even if 100% done is displayed for more than an hour. Microsoft has forgotten to include the file deletion process in percentage indication and for some unknown reason requires a very long time to delete thousands of files no longer needed because of being replaced already by newer Windows security updates. Please note that *Windows Update Cleanup* never done before can really take hours to complete, especially on Windows 8/8.1/10 where it takes always much longer as on Windows 7.

Finally clean up also the file cache(s) of the used internet browser(s) to get more free storage space on running already out of free storage space.